# Should there always be an Apache in front of a Tomcat (and why)?

Tags: apache, tomcat

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What should Apache serve and what should Tomcat serve?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2330780/what-should-apache-serve-and-what-should-tomcat-serve)

Posting an Apache HTTP server in front of a Tomcat seems to be very common. What are the reasons for that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2330780/what-should-apache-serve-and-what-should-tomcat-serve